# Measuring variation of saturated vapour pressure with temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

Is it possible to measure variation of saturated vapour pressure of water with time.I just hesitate about it.My suggested procedure which is incomplete is given below

**Procedure that I would like to suggest:** (It's incomplete)

- Take a capillary tube and trap an air column using thread of water as shown in below diagram

[image]

Obviously we need to heat this in order to  increase temperature .So we may need stuff like Bunsen burner . But after that how can I proceed ?

And I would like to know the your suggestions that would tally .

Comment: No one out here who can answer this?